# How do I handle empty response in GraphQL query using GraphQL for dotnet?

Tags: .net, graphql-dotnet

We are using the GraphQL client NuGet package (https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client) and

in our .NET 4.7.2 solution, we are currently, calling an GraphQL API like this:

```
protected SomeService(ILogger logger, IGraphQLClient client)
{
    _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
    _client = client ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(client));
}

public async Task<T> ExecuteMutation<T>(GraphQLRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        var response = await _client.SendMutationAsync<T>(request);
        return response.Data;
    }
    catch (GraphQLHttpRequestException ghre)
    {
        _logger.Error(ghre.Message, ghre);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

However, the API we are calling is not always returning an object. Sometimes, we just get an `HTTP 200 OK` response code back.

It seems that there is no method overload on the `GraphQLClient`, that can be used when there is only an HTTP response code.

How do we handle that scenario?